# Floating Fo:leader in Right to left (Arabic) language

Tags: java, pdf, css-float, apache-fop, arabic-support

I am not able to achieve floating fo:leader inside an fo:table. I need this because I want to show leader dots before the text, for ARABIC (right to left) language.

'''

```
 <fo:table>
     <fo:table-body>
         <fo:table-row>
              <fo:table-cell>
                   <fo:block font-family="Liberation Serif" font-size="8pt" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" color="#000000" text-align-last="justify">
                          <fo:float float="left">
                                <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots" leader-length="100%" font-size="8pt"/>
                          </fo:float>
                          <fo:float float="right">
                                    0000: Net Income
                          </fo:float>
                   </fo:block>   
             <fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

'''

I need to align the dots with the bottom of the text when the text wraps.

I want the output as following:

```
   Net
```

....   Income

But I am not able to get the above output. Instead I get the following:

..... Net
Income

Apparently Apache FOP does not support fo:float inside fo:table.  So i tried with the following but to no avail:

fo:inline-container inside another fo:inline-container
fo:list-block with fo:list-item

Finally I tried with another fo:table and it worked to a certain extent. But I need a better way than using fo:table.

'''

```
   <fo:table>
    ....

       <fo:block font-family="Liberation Serif" font-size="8pt" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" color="#000000" text-align-last="justify">
             <fo:table wrap-option="no-wrap" overflow="hidden" border-collapse="separate">
                   <fo:table-body>
                         <fo:table-row>
                             <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block><fo:leader leader-pattern="dots" leader-length.optimum="100%" font-size="14pt"/></fo:block>
                             </fo:table-cell>
                             <fo:table-cell>
                                  <fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">Net Income</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
       </fo:block>
      ...
</fo:table>
```

'''